# SQL Group by Data conditional filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table data as follows:

```
Customer    Level   Dept
AAA 1   Parent
AAA 2   Corporate
AAA 3   SmallBusiness
BBB 1   Parent
BBB 2   StateLevel
BBB 3   Education
BBB 4   RegionLevel
CCC 1   Parent
CCC 2   Sales
CCC 3   Healthcare
CCC 4   Online
CCC 5   Web
```

Conditions:
If Level=2 and Dept=Corporate

> User Department is Corporate

else if Level=3 and (Dept = Education or Dept = Sport)

> User Department is Education

else if Level=2 and Dept=Sales && Level=3 and Dept=HealthCare

> User department is HealthCare

DesiredOutput

```
Customer Department
AAA  Corporate
BBB  Education
CCC  Healthcare
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Did you attempt to write a query yourself?

Comment: Look into `SQl Case` statement *hint hint*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is via PIVOT

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Customer] varchar(50),[Level] int,[Dept] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('AAA',1,'Parent')
,('AAA',2,'Corporate')
,('AAA',3,'SmallBusiness')
,('BBB',1,'Parent')
,('BBB',2,'StateLevel')
,('BBB',3,'Education')
,('BBB',4,'RegionLevel')
,('CCC',1,'Parent')
,('CCC',2,'Sales')
,('CCC',3,'Healthcare')
,('CCC',4,'Online')
,('CCC',5,'Web')

Select Customer
      ,Dept     = concat(
                         case when [2] in ('Corporate') then 'Corporate' end
                        ,case when [3] in ('Education','Sport') then 'Education' end
                        ,case when [2] in ('Sales') and [3]='Healthcare' then 'Healthcare' end
                        )
 From (
        Select *
         From  @YourTable
         Pivot (max([Dept]) For [Level] in ([2],[3]) ) p
      ) A
```

**Returns**

```
Customer    Dept
AAA         Corporate
BBB         Education
CCC         Healthcare
```

Comment: Simply Awesome. The 3rd and condition was difficult to achieve for me, it is not simple case statement as others stated.

Comment: @SrinivasaRao Thanks.  This works with the sample data, but I am a little concerned over un-expected combinations... but I think you get the drift

Answer (score 2):

Simple case statement should do it... and I changed the last logical clause to an OR since a row can't be level 2 and level 3...

```
select distinct
customer,
case 
   when Level=2 and Dept='Corporate' then 'Corporate'
   when Level=3 and (Dept='Education' or Dept='Sport') then 'Education'
   when (Level = 2 and Dept='Sales') or (Level=3 and Dept='Healthcare') then 'Healthcare'
end as 'Department'
from
   SomeTable
where
   Level in (2,3)
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you need to update your `WHERE` clause.  Yours would reutrn AAA 3 NULL for the 'SmallBusiness' record in there.  +1, though.

Comment: I want and condition here, when (Level = 2 and Dept='Sales') and (Level=3 and Dept='Healthcare') then 'Healthcare', How this can be done?

Comment: it can't @SrinivasaRao, how would meet that criteria? A row is either level 1-5 not 3 & 2.

Answer (score 1):

You actually aren't grouping at all here - you're creating a new column based on conditions of the existing columns.  You want to use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Level = 2 AND Dept = 'Corporate' THEN 'Corporate' 
            WHEN Level = 3 AND (Dept = 'Education' OR Dept = 'Sport') THEN 'Education'
            WHEN (Level = 2 AND Dept = 'Sales') OR (Level = 3 AND Dept = 'HealthCare') THEN 'HealthCare'
            ELSE NULL END AS [Department]
FROM [YourTableName]
WHERE (Level = 2 AND Dept = 'Corporate')
OR    (Level = 3 AND (Dept = 'Education' OR Dept = 'Sport'))
OR    (Level = 2 AND Dept = 'Sales') 
OR (Level = 3 AND Dept = 'HealthCare')
```

Adjust your logic accordingly - the way your question was formatted it's difficult to know where the parenthesis should go - and they ARE important.

EDIT:  Added a `WHERE` clause per @scsimon's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @scsimon, but I didn't see any filtering request in the OP.  What would the `WHERE` clause contain?

Comment: well, you query would return something like AAA 1   Parent as well where it's not in the expected results. Check my answer

Comment: @scsimon You're right - he didn't say it but clearly that's what he needs.  I updated the answer.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: i want and condition here, WHEN (Level = 2 AND Dept = 'Sales') and (Level = 3 AND Dept = 'HealthCare') THEN 'HealthCare'

Answer (score 1):

Build something on these terms :

```
Case
when (level = 2 AND Dept = 'Corporate') Then Corporate
when (level = 3 AND Dept in ('Education','Sport)) Then Education
when (level = 2 AND Dept = 'Sales') Then Healthcare
when (level = 3 AND Dept = 'Healthcare') Then Healthcare
Else Null
End as col
```

Comment: `else null` is implied (you don't have to put it, it will be there by default). Just FYSA--though i do like seeing it for readability.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a case when

```
   select customer, 
        case when dept = 'Corporate' and level = 2 then 'Corporate'
             when ( dept =  'Education' or dept ='Sport' and level = 2 then 'Education'
             when  (level = 2 and dept ='Sales') and ( level=3 and dept = 'HealthCare' ) then 'HealthCare'
             else 'Unknow' end my_dept
  from table
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your logic it goes like:

```
SELECT Customer,
    CASE WHEN Level=2 AND Dept='Corporate' THEN 'Corporate'
         WHEN Level=3 AND (Dept='Education' OR Dept='Sort') THEN 'Education'
         WHEN Level=2 AND (Dept='Sales' AND Level=3) AND Dept='HealthCare'
         END AS [Department] FROM [YourTable]
```